# Import file from assets folder (own .ext)

Tags: angular, angular12

I have a file in my assets folder called data.myext

As you can see the extension is custom.

The data inside looks like this:

```
mydata = [
    {
      "name": “SOMENAME”,
      ‘value’: : 01345
    }
  ]
```

I want to import this to my `app.component.ts / html` and read it like this:

For example:

```
{{ mydata.name }} or from the .ts file using ... `mydata.name`
```

How can this be done?

Comment: import your json file in to yr module so u can fetch data to your component, you can set your array as 0 if there is only one object in yr array `{{mydata[0].name}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mydata is not Array. You can render object like this.

App.component.html

```
mydata[0].name
```

Loop example

```
<div *ngFor="let item of mydata">
    <span>{{ item.name }}</span>
</div>
```